Como crear un elemento doom y añadirlo al codigo?
En términos generales, para añadirlo a cualquier código. No termino de comprender como utilizarlo en la codificación

document.createElement("Elemento") por ej, document.createElement("div") y luego lo agregas al dom

Para añadirlo al doom, usa document.appendChild. te queda de tarea buscar tu mismo el uso, recuerda que esto no es un foro si no una pagina donde se responden preguntas especificas basadas en una investigacion previa que tu habras realizado, asi que te invito a que investigues

Si es que entendí bien, tu pregunta está al revés: Como crear elementos por código y añadirlo al DOM. Sé que es dificil formular una pregunta de algo que no se entiende, pero debes esforzarte más en ello. Te falta agregar algún código que no entiendas, explicar que es lo que quieres lograr y que es exactamente lo que no entiendes

El DOM es la representación en memoria de la estructura de un documento HTML, y puedes manipularlo con JavaScript para agregar, eliminar o modificar elementos en una página web.
Vamos a hacer un ejemplo sencillo para que te sea mas facil entenderlo
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ejemplo de creación de elementos DOM</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contenedor"></div>

  <script>
    // Creamos un nuevo elemento <p>
    var nuevoParrafo = document.createElement("p");
    
    // Creamos un nodo de texto para agregar al párrafo
    var texto = document.createTextNode("Este es un nuevo párrafo creado con JavaScript.");
    
    // Añadimos el nodo de texto al párrafo
    nuevoParrafo.appendChild(texto);
    
    // Añadimos el párrafo al elemento con id "contenedor" en el DOM
    document.getElementById("contenedor").appendChild(nuevoParrafo);
  </script>
</body>
</html>

En este caso, creamos un nuevo elemento  (párrafo) utilizando document.createElement("p"). Luego creamos un nodo de texto utilizando document.createTextNode() y lo agregamos al párrafo recién creado con appendChild(). Finalmente, añadimos el párrafo al elemento con el id "contenedor" en el DOM.
Este es solo un ejemplo básico. Dependiendo de tus necesidades, puedes realizar operaciones más complejas con el DOM, como agregar atributos, eventos, estilos, botones a formularios, etc...
Te recomiendo que investigues mas sobre esto y mas si estas pensando en dedicarle tiempo al desarrollo web o frontend ya que se utiliza muchisimo y es de las funciones mas importantes
